# Pseint: suma de números enteros

Tags: pseint

Lo que pasa es que quiero que el programa que estoy haciendo sume 10 números enteros. Creo que tengo todo el código bien, pero no suma los números, dice que la suma  es 0.
este es el código:

```
Algoritmo suma10numeros
    cont<-1
    acum<-0
    Mientras cont<-10 Hacer
        Escribir 'Digite un número'
        Leer n
        acum<-acum+n
        cont<-cont+1
    FinMientras
    Escribir 'La suma de los números es: ',acum
FinAlgoritmo
```

Answer (score 1):

El problema que le veo a tu codigo es que tienes una signación donde no va

```
Mientras cont<-10 Hacer
```

Allí le estás diciendo que mientras se le pueda asignar a la variable `cont` el valor 10 haga el ciclo.

Te recomiendo poner un poco más estricta tu sintaxis para verificar adicionalmente la lextura de datos.